# How to overlay jpg file as bitmap file on mapview in osmdroid

Tags: android, bitmap, overlay, osmdroid

I showed a photo on the map using the osmdroid and first methods.
Now I want to read a jpeg format picture from the device memory and show it as a bitmap on the map. The code does not give an error. But the photo is not displayed. please guide me. The following are the first and second method codes.

```
/// first method
GroundOverlay myGroundOverlay = new GroundOverlay();
        myGroundOverlay.setPosition(overlayCenterPoint);
        Drawable d = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_imageonmap_test2, null);

        myGroundOverlay.setImage(d.mutate());
        //myGroundOverlay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        myGroundOverlay.setDimensions(2000000.0f);
        myGroundOverlay.setTransparency(0.25f);
        myGroundOverlay.setBearing(0);
        mMapView.getOverlays().add(myGroundOverlay);

        mMapView.invalidate();
////// second method
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/osmdroid/20190722033213_1440103389.jpg");
        Bitmap bitmap2 = src.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);



        GroundOverlay myGroundOverlay2 = new GroundOverlay();

        myGroundOverlay2.setPosition(overlayCenterPoint);
        //myGroundOverlay2.setImageBitmap(src);
        myGroundOverlay2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
        //myGroundOverlay2.setDimensions(2000.0f);
        //myGroundOverlay2.setTransparency(0.25f);
        myGroundOverlay2.setBearing(0);
        mMapView.getOverlays().add(myGroundOverlay2);
        mMapView.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using OSMBonusPack GroundOverlay. 
Your code in method 1 seems correct (even if dimension seems huge). 
In method 2, setDimensions is missing.

Did you try the [OSMBonusPack tutorial](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_5#18-using-groundoverlay) "as is" (same position/dimension, same bitmap from resources)?

Also, try: "setBearing(0.0f);" (I'm not confident about implicit cast from int to float)